# I have been trying to log request/response using Play Framework but i am not able to log response but request in logging

Tags: java, logging, filter, playframework, interceptor

This the filter i am using.

```js
package filters;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletionStage;
import java.util.function.Function;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import akka.stream.Materializer;
import play.Logger;
import play.mvc.*;

public class LoggingFilter extends Filter {

    @Inject
    public LoggingFilter(Materializer mat) {
        super(mat);
    }

    @Override
    public CompletionStage<Result> apply(
            Function<Http.RequestHeader, CompletionStage<Result>> nextFilter,
            Http.RequestHeader requestHeader) {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        return nextFilter.apply(requestHeader).thenApply(result -> {
            long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long requestTime = endTime - startTime;

            Logger.info("{} {} {} took {}ms and returned {}",
                    requestHeader.method(), requestHeader.getHeaders().toMap(), requestHeader.uri(), requestTime, result.status());

            return result.withHeader("Request-Time", "" + requestTime);
        });
    }

    public CompletionStage<Result> Response(
            Function<ResponseHeader, CompletionStage<Result>> nextFilter,
            ResponseHeader responseHeader) {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        return nextFilter.apply(responseHeader).thenApply(result -> {
            long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long responseTime = endTime - startTime;

            Logger.info("{}  took {}ms and returned {}",
                    responseHeader, responseTime, result.status());

            return result.withHeader("Request-Time", "" + responseTime);
        });
    }
    
}
```

I know i created wrong method for response but i also new to this java and filter. but i am stuck here if anyone aware of mdc/interceptor method for play framework kindly help for the same.
Thanks

Comment: What do you want to do exactly?

Comment: Hi @VM4, i am trying to print request and response in my logs using play-framework filter but i am only able to log request but not response by using above code

Comment: I'm pretty sure `result` has the data you want. What exactly do you want to print from response?

Comment: @VM4 I am new to play framework as well as java would you tell what result should i use to get back response body and print it in log

Comment: @VM4 any help on this?

Comment: Can you give an example of what you want to see?

Comment: i want to see response as string from result()  that filter gives. but from result am not getting any data from there result(), only getting status and response time from there. no response body neither header.